# DataTable plugin jQuery child rows

Tags: jquery, datatables

My problem is that I don't know the way when only one child row can be open. I was trying to do it different ways but none was successful. I use the code from this link [Datatable child rows](https://datatables.net/examples/api/row_details.html).

In the example you can open each row simultaneously but I need it work as if you try to open one row during another is open, first one has to get closed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to close all other rows before using

```
    $('#example tbody tr').each(function (index, item) 
    {
        // console.log($(this).html());
        var row = table.row( $(this) );

        row.child.hide();
        $(this).removeClass('shown');
    });
```

https://jsfiddle.net/m674ebtv/5/